# Unable to access USB after unplugging by mistake

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I was transferring some files to my USB and I pulled that USB out by mistake when I was moving my laptop. When I try to access it this error shows:

[image]

Any words of wisdom to fix/mount it without data loss?

Comment: What file system is there? FAT32, NTFS, exFAT, ext4 ...?

Comment: The HDD is Ext4 and I was transferring to NTFS USB.

Comment: Then you have a fair chance to repair the file system when booted into Windows and using Windows tools. See this link for more details, [Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Comment: Nice.
Is there a chance to provide exact code to fix it?
I'm not some of the superuser to Linux =(

gparted says that USB is /dev/sdb locate

Comment: It is easy to do it with the graphical tools **in Windows**, or with `chkdsk X: /f` according to the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Fixed it =) 
Thanks 4 link/help

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad I could help you solve your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a fair chance to **repair the NTFS file system when booted into Windows** and using Windows tools. See this link for more details,

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Often when a pendrive does not work, it is not bricked, but the file system or partition table is damaged. This can be repaired with the same kind of tools as are used for hard disk drives.

Repair Windows file systems (FAT and NTFS) with Windows tools: a graphical tool or the following command line,

```
chkdsk /f X:
```

or if you suspect bad sectors,

```
chkdsk /r X:
```

where `X:` is the drive letter (volume letter) for the target partition as seen from Windows.

Comment: That's the answer that I'd have given, too, though it's nothing more than copy and pasting the text from the screenshot... :P

Comment: You are right, @0x01,  There was another user who wanted me to make my comment into an answer. (Otherwise I would have left it with the comment because the problem was already solved.)